# What is the Store folder in Click House?

Tags: database, clickhouse

What is the Store folder in Click House?
There is a folder called Store in Click House and it has a very large volume.
While I don't have one more database and its size is 1 gig, but the Store folder is almost 8 gig.
Can this folder be deleted?
There is little information on the Internet about this folder.
[image]

the size of my database:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is where the ClickHouse data is actually stored in recent ClickHouse versions. The `/data` directory contains symlinks to the `/store` sub directory where the data is for each table is actually kept.  https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/15504
So deleting that directory entirely will lose all of your data.

In most cases if you drop tables or whole databases from ClickHouse, the corresponding `/store` directory is also deleted.  However, in some situations (crashes, etc.) these directories can get out sync.

If that happens you can selectively delete `/store` subdirectories if you are confident they contain data that ClickHouse no longer knows about.  You can tell what `/store` directories ClickHouse is using by looking at the symlinks in the `/data` directory.  You can find the specific symlink associated with a table in `/data/<database_name>/<table_name>`

For example, on my local machine the `system` database is using three symlinks in store:

```
m1 geoff@GeoffMac: ~/chrun ls -la data/system
total 0
drwx------   5 geoff  staff   160 Jan  3 05:26 .
drwx------  49 geoff  staff  1568 Jan  6 18:34 ..
lrwxr-x---   1 geoff  staff    66 Jan  3 05:26 metric_log -> /Users/geoff/chrun/store/57f/57fbc8e9-14ed-4cbc-9c9d-28ae69ff196f/
lrwxr-x---   1 geoff  staff    66 Jan  3 05:26 query_log -> /Users/geoff/chrun/store/d13/d13002dd-92c1-49b2-8dac-16ae1a63efef/
lrwxr-x---   1 geoff  staff    66 Jan  3 05:26 session_log -> /Users/geoff/chrun/store/6dd/6dd443b3-44cf-4254-8767-ed8fd2933102/
```

By checking your `/data` symlinks again the `/store` directory you should be able to determine what `/store` directories aren't being used.  (Someone could write a script for this)

Comment: The size of my database is less than 1 gig, so how come it took 8 gigs of space? I updated my question

Comment: The most likely reason is that you had data that you deleted from ClickHouse (so it's not referenced in the data directory) but for some reason wasn't removed from the file system.  So ClickHouse doesn't report it, but it's still in the `/store` directory.  To solve this, delete directories in `/store` that aren't symlinked by anything under `/data`

Comment: How to find out directories in /store that aren't symlinked by anything under /data? can you explain more? I don't know where to run this command `~/chrun ls -la data/system`

Comment: try to look in SQL WHERE active=0 parts look https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/parts/ for details

moreover, if you use just DROP TABLE for Atomic engine
data stay on disk in 480 second